# Image load in weird display in PyQt5

Tags: python, image, user-interface, pyqt5, gimp

I am developing an app using PyQt5 that loads a simple PPM format image.

Most of all PPM format images loads well and perfectly. But there is one single image the insists in load in a weird way.

On the left the PPM format image that loads well. On the right the PPM image that loads weird in my app but it loads perfectly in GIMP and others Image Editor Softwares. Any hints?

[image]

This is how the same image (on the right) load in GIMP:

[image]

To load the images I'm using the default code from PyQt5 tutorial as follow:

```
self.image1 = QLabel(self)
self.path1 = 'images/original.ppm'
self.pixmap1 = QtGui.QPixmap(self.path1)
self.pixmap1 = self.pixmap1.scaled(250, 250, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
self.image1.setPixmap(self.pixmap1)
self.image1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


self.image2 = QLabel(self)
self.path2 = 'images/original_sharpen.ppm'
self.pixmap2 = QtGui.QPixmap(self.path2)
self.pixmap2 = self.pixmap2.scaled(250, 250, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
self.image2.setPixmap(self.pixmap2)
self.image2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share the image

Comment: Here is the image https://github.com/zandree/pyqt5-image/blob/master/original_sharpen.ppm